# How to use ScalaCheck's collect and classify in ScalaTest?

Tags: scala, scalatest, scalacheck

The following use of `Prop.collect((a, b))` isn't printing the statistics as expected even though the test runs successfully.

```
import org.scalacheck.Prop
import org.scalatest.{GivenWhenThen, PropSpec}
import org.scalatest.prop.{Checkers, GeneratorDrivenPropertyChecks}

import org.scalacheck.Prop.AnyOperators

class AccountSpecWithMarkup extends PropSpec with Checkers with GeneratorDrivenPropertyChecks {

  property("max") {
    check({
      (a:Int, b:Int) => {

        Prop.collect((a, b)) {

          a != b || a == b
        }
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An old question, probably long since answered or worked around, but since I'm a scalacheck newbie trying to figure out the ropes, I'll volunteer a response.

Not sure why your example doesn't work as expected, but this simpler test does the trick (in Scalacheck 1.14):

```
import org.scalacheck.Properties
import org.scalacheck.Prop.{forAll,collect}

object AccountSpecWithMarkup extends Properties("AccountSpecWithMarkup") {

  property("max") = forAll { (a: Int, b: Int) =>
    collect((a, b)) {
      a != b || a == b
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the test is now an `object` extending `Properties`. The `Properties.property` val is of type `PropertySpecifier`, which encapsulates mutable state (a collection of `Props`) and has an `update` method. This line

```
property("max") = forAll { ... }
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
property.update("max", forAll{ ... })
```

where the `forAll` generates a value of type `Prop`. This `Prop` value is accumulated for later evaluation using implicit `Arbitrary[Int]` generators to generate test values for `a` and `b`, which are collected by `collect` for reporting in the test results.

Here's the first few lines of a successful test run

```
+ AccountsSpectWithMarkup.max: OK, passed 100 tests.
> Collected test data: 
4% (-2147483648,2147483647)
2% (1,2147483647)
2% (-1,-1)
2% (-1,0)
1% (-1,-1128775662)
1% (501893471,-2147483648)
1% (0,0)
1% (1529964222,-1507103054)
1% (36753817,-2147483648)
1% (2147483647,535423354
```

Comment: I think the question is about usage in scalatest.PropSpec not scalacheck.Properties